# SQL optional match based on number of matches in other table & optional column match

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to solve an issue with a left join with two large tables (150k x 300k rows).

I have a key that should be unique, but sometimes isn't, in the format of 11002_13202. It is possible that this value occurs twice. There is an additional column that provides information on the uniqueness, which is provided like 'AAA'. I can add a where clause which would check for the match on the key AND the additional info (let's say 11002_13202_AAA). This will prevent wrong matches.

However, sometimes the additional field might be AAA in table B, which mismatches with the additional field in table A, and there is only one match on the key when joined.

Is it possible to optionally match on the additional field IF more than one join is done, and join anyways when there is only 1 match and the additional field is not necessarily equal between both tables?

Hoping to achieve the following result after joining:

| Table A key | Table B key | Additional Field A | Additional Field B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11002_13202 | 11002_13202 | AAA | AAA |
| 11002_13202 | NULL | BBB | NULL |
| 92321_32322 | 92321_32322 | BBB | AAA |
| 2310_23123 | NULL | AAA | NULL |
| 2310_23123 | NULL | BBB | NULL |
| 2310_23123 | 2310_23123 | CCC | CCC |
| 23821_2322 | NULL | BBB | NULL |
| 23821_2322 | 23821_2322 | BBB | BBB |

Sample data table A

| Table A key | Additional Field A |
| --- | --- |
| 11002_13202 | AAA |
| 11002_13202 | BBB |
| 92321_32322 | BBB |
| 2310_23123 | AAA |
| 2310_23123 | BBB |
| 2310_23123 | CCC |
| 23821_2322 | AAA |
| 23821_2322 | BBB |

Sample data table B

| Table B key | Additional Field B |
| --- | --- |
| 11002_13202 | AAA |
| 92321_32322 | AAA |
| 2310_23123 | CCC |
| 23821_2322 | BBB |

Comment: Please don't tag conflicting products; I've removed the conflicting tags, you'll need to [edit] the question to (re)tag the appropriate product.

Comment: @Larnu, apologies, I readded SQL server.

Comment: Some sample data and expected results will help us help you here, we only have expected results here, which doesn't help us understand what your data looks like. Though from the description we have, it sounds like that the design could be the issue here.

Comment: Why does `92321_32322,BBB` relate to `92321_32322,AAA` but `11002_13202,BBB` does not relate to `11002_13202,AAA`?

Comment: @Larnu is has to do with the number of occurences of the key column in table A. I receive (horrible) business data from different areas in my country, which is the additional field in both tables. Sometimes data is wrongly supplied for multiple areas, so it has the wrong notation (Entered under AAA, but really is BBB). If the field is available and correct for one out of multiple keys that would otherwise match, than it should match where addField A = addField B. But in the case of only one match on the keys, it is acceptable that the two addFields are not equal.

Comment: Sounds like, in truth, that the data needs to be addressed; if the data is wrong, it needs to be corrected. Then you will get correct results. The comment doesn't explain why `11002_13202,BBB` isn't related to anything though; your comment above implies it should be related to *something* (even if it's not the same).

Comment: @Larnu, yes, the data is definitely the issue here. Right now the matching is done solely on the key from both tables, resulting in 11002_13202 joining table B twice when only one join should be done where the country areas match for the two or more keys (AAA = AAA). This design with the extra field would be optimal, but the data is so bad that the additional field isn't reliable, so therefore the wish to have an optional match and exclude the additional field when only one match is possible (so the key exists once in both tables). Unfortunately fixing the data is not an option...

Comment: *"Unfortunately fixing the data is not an option.."* I hate to say it, but whenever I see this I don't believe it. People saying that they "can't fix their data" is normally more a way of them saying "The person/business won't put the effort/resources into fixing the data." The problem with this is that getting a solution right now gets you something that "works", but it doesn't solve the route issue and the further you go down the rabbit hole the harder it gets to get *actual* working solutions.

Comment: Saying that, I do have an idea, but I'm not sure it'll work with more example results. If you *did* for example, have a row for `11002_13202,BBB` in both tables would theu not match, because `11002_13202` has already been matched for `AAA`?

Comment: @Larnu, maybe I should have elaborated, but given the resources that are available, it isn't feasible to fix it short term.. But the solution will be a 'quick & dirty' fix for sure, but I already made this clear to the client & business. And given your example, yes, 11002_13202,BBB would not be matched because is already matched for AAA where tableA.addField = 'AAA' and tableB.addField = 'BBB'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* my understanding is correct, you could use `ROW_NUMBER` to only return the value of table B's columns if it's the first row, and order it by if the values match, and then an arbitrary value, I use the "addition *field*" (they are **columns** not "fields") here:

```sql
SELECT *
INTO dbo.TableA
FROM (VALUES('11002_13202','AAA'),
            ('11002_13202','BBB'),
            ('92321_32322','BBB'))V([Key],Additional);
SELECT *
INTO dbo.TableB
FROM (VALUES('11002_13202','AAA'),
            ('92321_32322','AAA'))V([Key],Additional);
GO

SELECT A.[Key] AS AKey,
       CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.[Key] ORDER BY CASE A.[Key] WHEN B.[Key] THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, A.Additional) WHEN 1 THEN B.[Key] END AS BKey,
       A.Additional AS AAdditional,
       CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.[Key] ORDER BY CASE A.[Key] WHEN B.[Key] THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, A.Additional) WHEN 1 THEN B.Additional END AS BAdditional
FROM dbo.TableA A
     JOIN dbo.TableB B ON A.[Key] = B.[Key]; --Assumed INNER JOIN, might want to be a LEFT JOIN though?

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.TableA;
DROP TABLE dbo.TableB;
```

If you prefer, you could put the `ROW_NUMBER` expression into a CTE/derived table, so you don't need to repeat the logic:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT A.[Key] AS AKey,
           B.[Key] AS BKey,
           A.Additional AS AAdditional,
           B.Additional AS BAdditional,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.[Key] ORDER BY CASE A.[Key] WHEN B.[Key] THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, A.Additional) AS RN
    FROM dbo.TableA A
         JOIN dbo.TableB B ON A.[Key] = B.[Key]) --Assumed INNER JOIN, might want to be a LEFT JOIN though?
SELECT AKey,
       CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN BKey END AS BKey,
       AAdditional,
       CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN BAdditional END AS BAdditional
FROM CTE;
```

As mentioned in the comments though, the data is the fundamental problem here, and time should (*must*) be taken to address that. Getting a "working solution" now as an interim is "fine", but having the repeat odd logic like this only make things harder over time, not easier. You'll likely end up with needing to use `VIEW`s and (inline table type) `FUNCTION`s just to get datasets in a consumable format for your basic queries, which could end up hindering performance if the data is really bad.

Taking time to schedule fixes for your data in the new year should be something on the priority list.

Comment: The first solution provided works perfectly for my data in a select statement with the real cases behind the sample data, awesome! I will implement solution 2 in the join query for optimization. Thanks so much!